# Photo grid like the new flickr design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The new responsive photo grid on the new flickr is gorgeous. It's full screen and locks together in an interesting, varied pattern.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/delobbo

I'd like to emulate this for a project, but dont even know where to start. I've looked at the code a bit, but it's pretty difficult to understand exactly what's going on here.

Anyone have any ideas on how they've been able to accomplish such a flexible grid that fits together so well?

Comment: I answered that question for another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561064/displaying-images-like-google-image-search/37157988#37157988

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's not really that hard. your code has to perform the folloging steps:

1. choose a preferred row-height. this seems to be around `500px` on flickr. you can set a fixed value or choose a setting based on the clients screen resolution
2. get the available total width
3. start a new row
4. put in a photo and scale it to row-height and check your row-width
5. repeat *4.* until adding a photo makes your row-width exeed the total width
6. scale down the height of this row (and the contained photos) until the width fits
7. start the next line (see *3.*)

Comment: For step #3, where would you create the row? An actual physical DOM element row, or some form of temporary row in js?

Comment: i'd do it virtually and create the dom-elements afterwards, but it shouldn't be a problem to create the elements directly (maybe if there are _a lot_ of photos - but i havn't tested this)