# Photo grid like the new flickr design *in Django Template*

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to do this in Django: [Photo grid like the new flickr design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828170/photo-grid-like-the-new-flickr-design)

Although the answer is correct, I'm having issues understanding how to make this happen in a Django template. Wondering if someone can help fill this in for me:

1. choose a preferred row-height. **DONE**
2. get the available total width **DONE**
3. **start a new row *HELP: Confused how to do this with the django forloop, since the forloops just loop through the whole set***
4. **put in the a photo and scale it to row-height and check your row-width *HELP: Confused how to do this with the django forloop, since the forloops just loop through the whole set***
5. repeat 4. until adding a photo makes you row-width exeed the total width **DONE**
6. scale down the height of this row (and the contained photos) until the width fits**DONE**
7. start the next line (see 3.) **HELP: See #3**

As soon as I can figure out the forloop, I should be fine. Here's the basic forloop i'm using now:

```
    {% for photo in photos %}
        <li>
            <a>
                <img height="250" src="{{ photo.thumbnail_image_url }}">
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

I'm assuming the output I need will look something like this:

```
<div>
    <a><img></a>
    <a><img></a>
    <a><img></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a><img></a>
    <a><img></a>
    <a><img></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a><img></a>
    <a><img></a>
    <a><img></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry what's the problem with the for loop? would be good if you also post the expected html layout?

Comment: @AamirAdnan - main issue is with a unordered list, you're not really making rows, you're making one large list (at least the way i'm interpreting the directions). I'd assume with "rows" you'd need some kind of containing element, like a DIV

Comment: @AamirAdnan also, i added the html output

Comment: The solution to your problem is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845227/django-templates-group-items-in-threes