# Flickr Grid System

Tags: javascript, css, grid, masonry, jquery-isotope

How can I create a grid system like Flickr's explore page?  https://www.flickr.com/explore

I've looked into Isotope (isotope.pkgd.js) but I can't seem to be able to arrange the grid based on the size of the images.

So far this is what I came up with:

HTML:

```
<h1>Isotope - masonry layout mode</h1>

<div class="isotope">

  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div>   
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div>   
  <div class="item"></div>  
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div>   
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div>   
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item width2 "></div>
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 
  <div class="item"></div> 

</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- isotope ---- */

.isotope {
  background: #DDD;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clear fix */
.isotope:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .item ---- */

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}

.item.width2 { width: 200px; }
.item.height2 { height: 200px; }
```

JavaScript:

```
// external js:
// http://isotope.metafizzy.co/isotope.pkgd.js

$( function() {

  $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37157988/1291916

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure on what you mean with order by image size. But to get the effect of flickr i would try something like this:

**layoutMode: 'packery'**

```
$('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'packery',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 100
    }
});
```

Comment: It is important to state that the packery layout mode is not included in isotope.pkgd.js and must be installed separately.[packery layout](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metafizzy/isotope-packery/master/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js)